# onPress parameters doesn't change

Tags: react-native

I want to display a list of item and when I click each item, it will alert me it's value.

```
_onPressButton(i) { 
    Alert.alert('You tapped the button number ' + i)
}

_renderBlockLebel = (number) => {
    var items = [];
    for (var i=0; i < number; i++) { 
        items.push(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressButton(i)} key={i}>
                <View style={styles.boxItem}>
                    <Text>Level {i}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
    return items;
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.box}>{this._renderBlockLebel(18)}</View>
    );
}
```

I have 18 items, it displays nice but when I click at any items, it alert "You tapped the button number 18", the value I passed is not change.

What is wrong with my code? I am new to React Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are pressing the label, the value of `i` has reached to `number` (which is 18 is your case). You need to retain the value of `i` with each iteration. Change the `_onPressButton` declaration as

```
_onPressButton = (i) => () => { 
    Alert.alert('You tapped the button number ' + i)
}
```

Also change the `onPress` handler to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton(i)} key={i}>
```

Have a look at the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to consider a variable and it works.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  _onPressButton (n) {
    Alert.alert('You tapped the button number ' + n);
  }

  _renderBlockLebel = number => {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      const n = i;
      items.push(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressButton(n)} key={i}>
          <View style={styles.boxItem}>
            <Text>Level {i}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return items;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.box}>{this._renderBlockLebel(18)}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@gasparteixeira/alert-number

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I tested in both iOS and Android and it works here!

Comment: Last time it was not running properly but today it works. Thank you!